# rotate svg:line pivoted on one of its ends in d3

Tags: svg, rotation, d3.js

Im trying to swap the axes of my graph (`svg:line` elements) on pressing a button.
I want the transition to happen like the dials of a clock.

The line

```
d3.select(".yAxis").transition().duration(500).attr("transform", function() { 
  var value = invert?0:90;
  return "rotate("+value+" "+x1+","+y1+")";
});
```

is doing translation & rotation simultaneously which is not serving my purpose.

I want the line to just rotate about (x1,y1) and not translate & rotate.

How should I go about doing this?

For more clarity, here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uttamg911/U48x9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this problem really picked my curiosity but I think I found a solution. Basically the transform interpolation is not doing what you expect and you have to use a [string interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolateString).

```
d3.select(".xAxis")
      .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attrTween("transform", function() {
            var startAngle = invert ?-90:0;
            var endAngle = invert?0:-90;
            return d3.interpolateString(
                "rotate("+startAngle+" "+ x +" "+ y +")", 
                "rotate("+endAngle+" "+ x +" "+ y +")"
            );                  
        });
```

Also the interpolation call can be factored between the two axes since they have the same center of rotation.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KVUUb/

Comment: Awesome. I dint know about this interpolateString before. Thanks Joan!